# Is it possible for a C# application to read the notifications that an other app sends and do things accordingly?

Tags: c#, notifications

This is a console app and I want it to be ale to read the notifications from the Discord app. I want to get info about who I get a message from or from what server and which room, this is all in the notification.

Comment: Can you add some code of the console app which you have tried out so that we can guide you?

Comment: I would suggest to start by looking into discord developer portal. https://discord.com/developers/docs/intro